# Привязка ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> к табличному элементу управления

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Доброго времени суток! К какому элементу управления можно привязать ObservableCollection, чтобы отображение было бы в виде таблицы?

Comment: `DataGrid` и `DataGridTemplateColumn` с `ItemTemplat`ом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите расположить рисунки по сетке, то сделать это можно следующим образом.

1.Сделать модель представления, которая будет содержать информацию о ячейке с картинкой (самый простой случай - координаты) и саму картинку:

```
public sealed class BitmapVm
{
    public BitmapImage Image { get; }

    public int X { get; }

    public int Y { get; }
}
```

2.Создать коллекцию таких элементов, выставив их наружу в модели представления окна:

```
public sealed class MainVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<BitmapVm> Bitmaps { get; }
}
```

3.В представлении окна создать ItemsControl и установить Grid в качестве ItemsPanelTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bitmaps}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <!-- Количество строк и столбцов можно задавать Binding'ом, но придется повозиться -->
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

**UPD**

По предложению @FoggyFinder.

Модель представления главного окна:

```
public sealed class MainVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> Bitmaps { get; }
}
```

Представление:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bitmaps}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: @FoggyFinder, кстати, да. Хорошая идея.

Comment: отличное решение, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Точнее как-то так.

```
<DataGrid Name="f_Grid">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

и код

```
f_Grid.ItemsSource = yourCollectionBitmap;
```